# Files generated during ng build --prod --configuration=development are different from what publish targets expect to copy

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, angular-cli

I am very new to the DevOps side of things for Angular CLI and am encountering this problem with dotnet publish stage in the build pipeline.

What I am working on is an Asp.Net core 2.1 Angular 8 web project.
I had used a Asp.Net core Angular project template.

It had Angular 6 and the requirement is to work off of Angular 8.
hence I updated package.json to reflect the same.

When I run > ng build --prod --configuration=development, below are the files generated:

```
 chunk {0} runtime.741402d1d47331ce975c.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
  chunk {1} main.ad82baa5bb28a734da67.js (main) 2.32 MB [initial] [rendered]
  chunk {2} polyfills.6566791a677aeff5bc67.js (polyfills) 42.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
  chunk {3} polyfills-es5.28de8d190640d51d92af.js (polyfills-es5) 68.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
  chunk {4} styles.78e9718c847473f8c3a9.css (styles) 64.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
  chunk {scripts} scripts.03e042f1f102bf0e2ed8.js (scripts) 19.8 kB [entry] [rendered]
```

But what the publish targets expect to copy are different: Notice the Hash between filename and extension of each file:

```
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "wwwroot\clientapp\dist\fontawesome-webfont.912ec66d7572ff821749.svg" because it was not found. 
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "wwwroot\clientapp\dist\fontawesome-webfont.674f50d287a8c48dc19b.eot" because it was not found. 
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "wwwroot\clientapp\dist\fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8.woff2" because it was not found. 
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "wwwroot\clientapp\dist\fontawesome-webfont.b06871f281fee6b241d6.ttf" because it was not found. 
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "wwwroot\clientapp\dist\fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff" because it was not found. 
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "wwwroot\clientapp\dist\main.0d2c317a44a9c52889ec.js" because it was not found. 
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "wwwroot\clientapp\dist\polyfills.40bb869b748691701bbd.js" because it was not found. 
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "wwwroot\clientapp\dist\runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js" because it was not found. 
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "wwwroot\clientapp\dist\styles.afee324584e31a3b1e79.css" because it was not found. 
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

Expected Results:
dotnet publish build targets picks up the files generated during build and copies it over to wwwroot/clientapp/dist

Actual result:
dotnet publish build targets tries to look for files which are not existing. 
Suspecting if the template has some code to auto generate based on the old package.json references

Comment: Can you share your pipeline and your folders structure?

Comment: Can you share content of your *.csproj file?

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? If so, please share.